# Animating CALayer anchorPoint

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-animation, transform, calayer

I have successfully animated my layers' position and transform (rotation).

Now, I needed to animate the anchorPoint, but failed at all attempts! Even when I do this:

```
2012... App[6437:403] layer: 1, KeyPath: anchorPoint, fromValue: NSPoint: {1.05, 0.5}, toValue: NSPoint: {1.05, 0.5}, Duration: 2.5
```

This is an NSLog stuck before animating the layer.. The result I get is the layer moving to the left in the X-Axis waaaay too far, then coming back .. and repeating (since autoreverse is ON).

Note about the layers hierarchy:
SuperLayer has three sublayers that I am applying the animation on.

Why? How should the anchor point be animated?

My Code:

```
    NSArray* subKeyPath     = [keyPaths objectAtIndex:tag];
    NSArray* subToValue     = [toValues objectAtIndex:tag];
    NSArray* subDuration    = [durations objectAtIndex:tag];

    NSEnumerator* keyPathsEnum  = [subKeyPath objectEnumerator];
    NSEnumerator* toValuesEnum  = [subToValue objectEnumerator];
    NSEnumerator* durationsEnum = [subDuration objectEnumerator];

    NSString* keyPath;
    NSNumber* toValue;
    NSNumber* duration;

    while ((keyPath = [keyPathsEnum nextObject]) && (toValue = [toValuesEnum nextObject]) && (duration = [durationsEnum nextObject])) {
        CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:keyPath];

        id offsetToValue;
        if ([keyPath hasPrefix:@"position"]) {
        //I removed the position animation, since animating the anchorPoint should suffice
        } else if ([keyPath hasPrefix:@"anchorPoint"]) {
            //This was when I used anchorPoint.x float value         = [[subLayer valueForKeyPath:keyPath] floatValue] - ([toValue floatValue]/[[subLayer contents] size].width);
            offsetToValue       = [NSNumber valueWithPoint:CGPointMake(1.05, 0.5)];
            keyPath             = [keyPath substringToIndex:[keyPath length]-2];
        } else {
            offsetToValue       = toValue;
        }

...

        animation.toValue       = offsetToValue;
        animation.duration      = [duration floatValue];
        animation.fillMode      = kCAFillModeForwards;
        animation.repeatCount   = INFINITY;
        animation.autoreverses  = YES;
        animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

        [subLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:keyPath];

        //update the model

    }
```

I tried animating the "anchorPoint.x" keyPath, same result :(

Last note, I am writing a cocoa app, but animating the X value should be exactly the same on both cocoa and cocoa touch.

Comment: If I may comment on your code itself, it's nice & clean

Comment: Thanks @JamesGraham! I mostly work with devs who don't see value in such art when coding :/

Comment: It is a joy to read :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not gonna believe this (As if I am sitting with you from the beginning)..

Animating the position and the rotation was working properly without setting the `fromValue`. However, animating the anchor point required that I set the anchor point `fromValue` to the initial value!

```
animation.fromValue = [subLayer valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
```

Comment: That's bizarre. It almost sounds like a CA bug. You might want to log a bug report with Apple's Radar bug tracking system. Apple generally responds, and if it's a bug, it will bring it to their attention, and if not, you'll learn WHY it works that way.

Comment: Wow, I never used Radar, and never knew they'll respond that way. It is definitely worth checking out.